# Breadcrumbs not displaying in frontend and admin in Magento 2.2.4?

Tags: admin, magento2.2, template-hints

I don't know how to implement this task. In admin page, I have `stores->Configuration->Advanced->developer`

I have to choose to enable path hints in front page "yes".

But in Front-end not display breadcrumbs.

Can you please help me?

Comment: breadcrumbs is not visible only in product page or all page ?

Comment: Hi, breadcrumbs are not visible on all pages.

Comment: Are you using custom theme ?

Comment: yes. Smartwave Porto theme I am using.

Comment: Hi, Can you please help me?

Comment: @DileepKumar Search a code like <referenceBlock name="breadcrumbs" remove="true"/> in all the files

Comment: Hi @ Nikunj Vadariya, Sorry. My task is path hints not displaying in frontend and admin page. Can you please help me?

Comment: Hi @ Nikunj Vadariya, I need your help from path hints not showing in the front page.

Comment: @DileepKumar If you are using Magento 2.2 then on production mode, the template hint will not work.

Also, you need to check the setting at last level of scope mean store view scope is selected for it.

Comment: can you try cache disable after check working or not working?

Answer (score 0):

Porto has removed breadcrumb from home page that's why its **not displayed in home page.**

For product page , breadcrumb is not visible its because of **magento bug 2.2.4.** to solve this issue override breadcrumb.js file from your current theme.

> app/design/frontend/Smartwave/Porto/Catalog/view/frontend/web/js/product/breadcrumbs.js

```
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

define([
    'jquery',
    'Magento_Theme/js/model/breadcrumb-list'
], function ($, breadcrumbList) {
    'use strict';

    return function (widget) {

        $.widget('mage.breadcrumbs', widget, {
            options: {
                categoryUrlSuffix: '',
                useCategoryPathInUrl: false,
                product: '',
                categoryItemSelector: '.category-item',
                menuContainer: '[data-action="navigation"] > ul'
            },

            /** @inheritdoc */
            _render: function () {
                this._appendCatalogCrumbs();
                this._super();
            },

            /**
             * Append category and product crumbs.
             *
             * @private
             */
            _appendCatalogCrumbs: function () {
                var categoryCrumbs = this._resolveCategoryCrumbs();

                categoryCrumbs.forEach(function (crumbInfo) {
                    breadcrumbList.push(crumbInfo);
                });

                if (this.options.product) {
                    breadcrumbList.push(this._getProductCrumb());
                }
            },

            /**
             * Resolve categories crumbs.
             *
             * @return Array
             * @private
             */
            _resolveCategoryCrumbs: function () {
                var menuItem = this._resolveCategoryMenuItem(),
                    categoryCrumbs = [];

                if (menuItem !== null && menuItem.length) {
                    categoryCrumbs.unshift(this._getCategoryCrumb(menuItem));

                    while ((menuItem = this._getParentMenuItem(menuItem)) !== null) {
                        categoryCrumbs.unshift(this._getCategoryCrumb(menuItem));
                    }
                }

                return categoryCrumbs;
            },

            /**
             * Returns crumb data.
             *
             * @param {Object} menuItem
             * @return {Object}
             * @private
             */
            _getCategoryCrumb: function (menuItem) {
                return {
                    'name': 'category',
                    'label': menuItem.text(),
                    'link': menuItem.attr('href'),
                    'title': ''
                };
            },

            /**
             * Returns product crumb.
             *
             * @return {Object}
             * @private
             */
            _getProductCrumb: function () {
                return {
                    'name': 'product',
                    'label': this.options.product,
                    'link': '',
                    'title': ''
                };
            },

            /**
             * Find parent menu item for current.
             *
             * @param {Object} menuItem
             * @return {Object|null}
             * @private
             */
            _getParentMenuItem: function (menuItem) {
                var classes,
                    classNav,
                    parentClass,
                    parentMenuItem = null;

                if (!menuItem) {
                    return null;
                }

                classes = menuItem.parent().attr('class');
                classNav = classes.match(/(nav\-)[0-9]+(\-[0-9]+)+/gi);

                if (classNav) {
                    classNav = classNav[0];
                    parentClass = classNav.substr(0, classNav.lastIndexOf('-'));

                    if (parentClass.lastIndexOf('-') !== -1) {
                        parentMenuItem = $(this.options.menuContainer).find('.' + parentClass + ' > a');
                        parentMenuItem = parentMenuItem.length ? parentMenuItem : null;
                    }
                }

                return parentMenuItem;
            },

            /**
             * Returns category menu item.
             *
             * Tries to resolve category from url or from referrer as fallback and
             * find menu item from navigation menu by category url.
             *
             * @return {Object|null}
             * @private
             */
            _resolveCategoryMenuItem: function () {
                var categoryUrl = this._resolveCategoryUrl(),
                    menu = $(this.options.menuContainer),
                    categoryMenuItem = null;

                if (categoryUrl && menu.length) {
                    categoryMenuItem = menu.find(
                        this.options.categoryItemSelector +
                        ' > a[href="' + categoryUrl + '"]'
                    );
                }

                return categoryMenuItem;
            },

            /**
             * Returns category url.
             *
             * @return {String}
             * @private
             */
            _resolveCategoryUrl: function () {
                var categoryUrl;

                if (this.options.useCategoryPathInUrl) {
                    // In case category path is used in product url - resolve category url from current url.
                    categoryUrl = window.location.href.split('?')[0];
                    categoryUrl = categoryUrl.substring(0, categoryUrl.lastIndexOf('/')) +
                        this.options.categoryUrlSuffix;
                } else {
                    // In other case - try to resolve it from referrer (without parameters).
                    categoryUrl = document.referrer;

                    if (categoryUrl.indexOf('?') > 0) {
                        categoryUrl = categoryUrl.substr(0, categoryUrl.indexOf('?'));
                    }
                }

                return categoryUrl;
            }
        });

        return $.mage.breadcrumbs;
    };
});
```

after do setup upgrade and deploy. in product page breadcrumb is visible.